# Windows phone 8.1 run on phone not on virtual machine

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-emulator

I´ve got a question. If it is possible to run app on my phone. I know it´s silly question but when i created easy Hello world! app and i store it. It is stored as appx, appxupload and others files which i cant open in my phone. Yes on virtual machine its not a problem but on my phone it is problem. Is there way for store it and run it somehow? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register your phone?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx
then try to run it by setting your device as target.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes i did forget register my phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your application by simply setting device as your target device.
Or you can create an app package and deploy it using ApplicationDeployment tool.
More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/dn632395(v=vs.120).aspx